# Parsing google nearby places api problem with next page token (swift 3, 4)

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, token

i try to get the nearby places link with the pagetoken.
This is my class:

```
class Place: NSObject, MKAnnotation{
var name: String
var place_id: String
var rating: Double?
var vicinity: String?
var open_now:Bool?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var phone_number: String?
var timings: [String]?
var photos: [String]?
var reviews: [Review]?
var distance: Double?


init(name: String, place_id: String, locationCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    self.name = name
    self.place_id = place_id
    self.coordinate = locationCoordinate
}

var subtitle: String? {
    return vicinity
}

var title: String? {
    if name.isEmpty {
        return "(No Title)"
    } else {
        return name
    }
}
```

}//end Place

AND HERE IS THE PARSE FUNCTION

```
//---------------------------------------------------------
```

// PARSE PLACE
//---------------------------------------------------------

```
func parse(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [Place] {

 //   guard let status = dictionary["status"] as? String, status == "OK" else {
 //       print("Invalid status")
 //       return []
 //   }



    guard let array = dictionary["results"] as? [Any], array.count > 0 else {
        print("Expected 'results' array or Array is empty")
        return []
    }


    var searchResults: [Place] = []
    for resultDict in array
    {

        var place:Place
        if let resultDict = resultDict as? [String : Any]
        {

            if let name = resultDict["name"] as? String,
                let place_id = resultDict["place_id"] as? String,
                let geometryDict = resultDict["geometry"] as? [String : Any]
            {
                if let locationDict = geometryDict["location"] as? [String : Any] {
                    if let lat = locationDict["lat"] as? Double, let lng = locationDict["lng"] as? Double {

                        let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)

                        place = Place(name: name, place_id: place_id, locationCoordinate: coordinate)


                        if let rating = resultDict["rating"] as? Double {
                            place.rating = rating
                        }

                        if let vicinity = resultDict["vicinity"] as? String {
                            place.vicinity = vicinity
                        }

                        if let hoursDict = resultDict["opening_hours"] as? [String : Any] {
                            if let openNow = hoursDict["open_now"] as? Bool {
                                place.open_now = openNow
                                print("place.open_now \(String(describing: place.open_now))")
                            }
                        }

                        if location != nil {
                            let storeLocation: CLLocation =  CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                            place.distance = calculateDistanceToStore(storeCoordinate: storeLocation)
                        }

                        searchResults.append(place)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }//end for

    return searchResults
}
```

And here i create the url where i parse the dictionary:

```
func getPlacesUrl() -> String {

    let latitude = String(format: "%f", location!.coordinate.latitude)
    let longitude = String(format: "%f", location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let radius = String(format: "%.0f", Float(filterDict["selectedRadius"]!)! * 1000)
    let types = "Beachbar"
    let name = "Beachbar"


    let urlString = String("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(latitude),\(longitude)&radius=\(radius)&types=\(types)&name=\(name)&key=AIzaSyDG7ve7mQUbkuz9GyDrT6ArBJo98OqwwWI")

    //let url = URL(string: urlString)
    print("PLACES URL ==> \(urlString)")
    return urlString
}
```

I have made a function that is called from a button

```
@IBAction func loadMore(_ sender: Any) {
    ShowTokenResults()
}
```

My function gets inside the google api places link I created before,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.006924,23.670639&radius=90000&types=Beachbar&name=Beachbar&key=AIzaSyDG7ve7mQUbkuz9GyDrT6ArBJo98OqwwWI
```

, parses the json, takes the next page token, adds it to the first url that has been parsed before and parses again from each url with it's token.This is my function:

```
func ShowTokenResults() {

     searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    guard location != nil else {
        //showLocationServicesDeniedAlert()
        return
    }

    isLoading = true
    tableView.reloadData()
    hasSearched = true
    searchResults = []

    let parsedUrl = getPlacesUrl()

    Alamofire.request(parsedUrl).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        if let jsonDictionary = response.result.value as? [String:Any]
        {

                    for (key, value) in jsonDictionary {
                        if (key == "next_page_token") {

                            let possibleToken:String = value as! String
                            if (possibleToken != "") {
                            let myNewUrl = parsedUrl+"&pagetoken=\(possibleToken)"


                            Alamofire.request(myNewUrl).responseJSON { response in
                                debugPrint(response)

                                        if let jsonTokenDictionary = response.result.value as? [String:Any]
                                        {
                                        self.searchResults = self.parse(dictionary: jsonTokenDictionary)
                                        //print("PAGETOKEN=====\(pageToken)")
                                        //print("PARSING FROM==\(myNewUrl)")
                                        //print("TOKEN DICTIONARY==\(String(describing: jsonTokenDictionary))")

                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.isLoading = false
                                        self.searchResults.sort(by: { Double($0.distance!) < Double($1.distance!) })
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                            }

                                    return

                                    }

                                }
                            }else{
                                print("EMPTY TOKEN")
                            }
                        }
                    }//END FOR
                }

            }

}//end sshowTokenResults
```

My problem is that when it parses the first url without token in the link, everythings is ok.When parses the link with the token it prints it but founds empty the json of results in which are the keys and values of my data.This is my response

```
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x281500120> { URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.006827,23.670812&radius=90000&types=Beachbar&name=Beachbar&key=AIzaSyDG7ve7mQUbkuz9GyDrT6ArBJo98OqwwWI&pagetoken=CsQEMwIAAB41b9tTGDorw8SINaE18-ap_NHTB4o4RAZNIpD3ZIta9DvrM0jg8lupXxZnr7xHD7nINYr...... } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
    "public, max-age=300"
);
"Content-Encoding" =     (
    gzip
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    86
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Wed, 28 Nov 2018 00:35:45 GMT"
);
Expires =     (
    "Wed, 28 Nov 2018 00:40:45 GMT"
);
Server =     (
    "scaffolding on HTTPServer2"
);
Vary =     (
    "Accept-Language"
);
"alt-svc" =     (
    "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"44,43,39,35\""
);
"x-frame-options" =     (
    SAMEORIGIN
);
"x-xss-protection" =     (
    "1; mode=block"
);
```

} }

```
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
"html_attributions" =     (
);
results =     (
);
status = "INVALID_REQUEST";
```

}

Comment: finalUrl is a function call not a `string` variable

Comment: you have a function `finalUrl` that takes in a string.  You are calling this function here `let url = URL(string: finalUrl)` but you are not supplying `finalUrl` with a string and the function does not return a string.

Comment: But i think finalUrl is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your intention is to set the value of `let url` equal to a URL object given a string url.  However, you are calling a function `finalUrl` that has an argument of `parsedurl: String`.  This is why your error:

`Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> ()' to expected argument type 'String'`

The error message is telling you that you're trying to set a String to the value of a function aka Closure aka Lambda.

Perhaps you mean to have your `finalUrl` function return a string?

`func finalUrl() -> String`

Comment: I tried this but i  have this error in the return :Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Comment: Ah I see what you need to do.  Change `func finalUrl(parsedurl: String)` to `func finalUrl() -> String`.  This means it will not take any arguments/parameters, and it will return a String.

Comment: Afterwards you'll also need to add parentheses to your function call, i.e. change `let url = URL(string: finalUrl)` to `let url = URL(string: finalUrl())`

Comment: and the return of function finalUrl what will be? Now it's this : return self.finalUrl(parsedurl: myNewUrl)